# multiplying each element in a nested list by 2

Tags: python, list, nested

The problem is: Define a function called ex_4 that will multiply every element in the inner list by 2. For example:

```
ex_4([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]) ---> [[2, 4, 6], [8, 10], [12, 14, 16]]
```

Here's what I have.....

```
def ex_4(LL):
    return list(map(lambda x: x*2, LL[0])), list(map(lambda x: x*2, LL[1])),list(map(lambda x: x*2, LL[2]))

ex_4([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
--> ([2, 4, 6], [8, 10], [12, 14, 16])
```

This returns the result I'm looking for, however the answer is not returned as a nested list. I'd also like to be able to input additional lists to that, and not have to keep adding LL[3],LL[4], etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you can also *nest* the `map`s

```
list(map(lambda L: list(map(lambda x: x*2, L)), LL))
```

but in this case, it is more elegant here to use *nested* list comprehension:

```
[ [ 2*x for x in L ] for L in LL ]
```

So here the outer list comprehension iterates with `L` over the elements (sublists) of `LL`. For every such `L`, we "yield" the inner list comprehension, where we iterate with `x` over `L` and yield `2*x` for every element in `L`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!